# Sampling Frequency of a delta-sigma ADC

Tags: adc, sampling, oversampling

For instance, let's take this delta-sigma ADC:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22088c.pdf

To calculate the average current and other important values for various sampling scenarios I need the true sampling frequency of an ADC.
Most notes deal with SAR ADCs where this is obvious, but what about delta-sigma ADCs?

Let's take the mentioned ADC and consider its 18-bit mode.

In 18-bit mode, it will output 3.75 SPS (samples per second).

Now to prevent aliasing or calculate various stuff like e.g. requirements on time constants etc. I do not care about the data output rate, but about how many times the ADC really physically samples, right? So how do I know how many times the ADC samples, before it outputs an 18-bit sample at the end?

Let's say I want to measure a sensor output once every second (= 1Hz).

A delta-sigma ADC uses oversampling to generate a high bit output with a 1-bit ADC. So wouldn't the ADC need to physically sample about 4^(17-bit) * 1Hz = ~17GHz theoretically to achieve 18-bit output codes?

I'm confused, hope you can help me out, thank you.

Comment: What sinc filter have you implemented and what decimating factor? This is what determines the ENOB

Comment: Are you still measuring light?

Comment: You must define the slew rate of your signal to prevent aliasing !!!

Comment: Nothing implemented so far, im interested in calculating the right values so I can start playing around with prototyping and hopefully see calculated data matching with the measured data afterwards. :) So how could i determine the oversampling frequency of this delta sigma ADC? To calculate average current  I = F * C * V i need to know the samples/per conversion as well. So how do i calculate this for e.g. 18bit mode?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 2^17 not 4^17?

Comment: @immibis: idea was that you always need to quadruple current sample amount in order to gain an additional bit using oversampling. Correct me if im wrong though :).

Comment: @ henry modern oversampling ADCs will use complex "modulators", thus needing much less that 2^N samples per output conversion.